# INDEX LENGTH IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i have a question, i was reading the mysql doccumentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-indexes.html#column-indexes-spatial) and saw this...

> All storage engines support at least 16 indexes per table and a total index length of at least 256 bytes

but i was looking for an answer and i didn't find an answer that addresses my question, the question is, what does it mean "index length" and why 256 bytes if the size is usually much larger?

pd: english is not my native language

Comment: Please post link to documentation

Comment: Are you asking us to second-guess the design decisions of the various mysql storage engines?

Comment: @P.Salmon i already add it

Comment: @Shadow i'm a begginer men, that's why i ask

Answer (score 3):

Index length in this case means the size of the data type of the column (or columns) you include in the index. For example, an `INT` is 4 bytes, a `BINARY(10)` is 10 bytes, a `VARCHAR(10)` with utf8mb4 character set is up to 40 bytes (utf8mb4 may use up to 4 bytes per character).

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html for details on the storage of each data type.

You can make indexes of multiple columns. The total index length is the sum of the size of each column in that index. For example, two `INT` columns plus a `VARCHAR(10)` would be 4 + 4 + 40 = 48 bytes.

The minimum of 256 bytes mentioned in that documentation means all storage engines allow index length to be *at least* 256 bytes.

InnoDB is the default storage engine, and it allows index length to be up to 3072 bytes in the current version MySQL 8.0. For example, this would support an index on a `VARCHAR(768)` with utf8mb4.

Comment: already i add a link in the question